# is $\int_{-1}^{1} dsgn = 2?$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

This basically came from Tao's analysis book, (volume I, ex. 11.8.5)

And I'm not sure whether it is the case where I computed incorrectly or it is an error in the book.

So since we integrating the constant function the integral should be equal to $sgn[[-1,1]]$ where $\alpha [<a,b>]$ is calculated as $\alpha (b)- \alpha (a)$ 
thus we should get $$sgn(1)-sgn(-1)=1-(-1)=2.$$

Comment: It should be $2$, forget what i said

Comment: You can prove that $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) \text{dsign}(x) = 2f(0)$, if $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. Note that this result doesn't depend on the limits of integrations (it suffices the upper limit is positive, and bottom is negative)

Comment: What does the book say?  Also, what does this integral mean?  Is it a Riemann-Stieltjes integral?  A Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tao's book, but I would have thought that since $sgn$ is locally constant, that $dsgn=0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey right what in the Adam's comment but instead of 2f(0) it simply says f(0) that's whan got me confused a little bit, and yes it is a  Riemann-Stieltjes

Comment: Book is wrong then, or do you want a proof? You can do it yourself from the definition

Comment: @Adam no I got it! you confirmed for what I thought

Comment: @Adam are you sure though that it is sufficient for f to only be continuous at 0? In the book he says f is continuos at all points in the domain and I tend to agree simply because otherwise it could be unbouded and not Riemann-Stiltjes integrable

Comment: I'm sure being continuous art $x=0$ suffices

Comment: @Adam but continuity at 0 doesn't provide global boundness, take tg(x) for example from -pi/2 to + pi/2, the function is continuous at 0 but unbounded hence not Riemann-Stiltjes integrable and it has nothing to do with dsgn(x) (boundness is a necessary condition for a function to be Riemann-Stiltjes integrable)

Comment: well I'm not sure, maybe you're talking about some more general notion of integral, Riemann and Riemann-Stiltjes as far as I got

Comment: I see no such thing in the definition of Riemann-Stieltjes integral. I know it's the case for Riemann integral. Can you provide me with, let's say, a link?

Comment: @Adam https://imgur.com/a/JJDNUWR

Comment: @Adam this is necessary because due to this definition there can be simply no piece-constant functions that majorize or minorize our function and the following sets would be empty and lower and upper integrals can not be matched then.

Comment: But that's when we want to define upper and lower integral, which we don't have to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that a small explanation here would be nice.

If you are working with d f(x), it is usually worth it to write it as f'(x) dx. Now, sgn'(x) does not exist as a function but as one does by introducing the number i in complex analysis one can define something similar here, namely distributions. Mathematically, we can define the delta dirac distribution $\delta$ as an operator that if applied to a function f, it returns f(0) (one could see this operation as integration of $\delta\cdot f$ over any region that contains 0).

Derivatives of a function such as sgn(x) can also be defined in the setting of distribution theory and it might come as no surprise that $sgn'(x) = 2\cdot\delta(x)$ with $\delta$ the dirac distribution (since this function has a jump of size 2 at 0). This means that if you integrate 1 against d(sgn), one could also view this as integrating $1\cdot(2\cdot\delta(x))$ against $d x$. Since 0 is contained in the interval over which you are integrating, this implies that the answer is 2 (the integral over $\delta(x)$ equals 1)

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight!